# Given $F[N,M]=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}(-1)^{N-1-m}(m+1)^M)/(m!(N-1-m)!)$, show $F[N,N-1]=1$ and $F[N,M]=0$ for $M<N-1$

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

The function defined by
$$
F[N,M]=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{N-1-m}(m+1)^M}{m!(N-1-m)!}
$$
where $N,M$ are positive integers. I want to show
$$
F[N,N-1]=1,\ F[N,M]=0
$$
for $N>2$ and $M<N-1$. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: In standard hypergeometric notation, your sum is
$$\frac{(-1)^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}\,{}_{m+1}F_m\left(\begin{matrix}1-N,2,\dots,2\\1,\dots,1\end{matrix}\right).$$
Your identities are special cases of the Karlsson-Minton identities (Minton, J. Math. Phys. 11 (1970) 1375-1376; Karlsson, J. Math. Phys. 12 (1971) 270-271). There are many ways to prove these, e.g. using integral representations, partial fraction identities or difference operators.

Comment: For $f(x)=(x+1)^M$ the number $(N-1)!F[N,M]$ is the $(N-1)$-st finite difference at point 0, thus the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can derive an explicit formula:
\begin{split}
F(N,M) &= [y^M]\frac{M!}{(N-1)!}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}m (-1)^{N-1-m} e^{(m+1)y} \\
&= [y^M]\frac{M!}{(N-1)!} e^y (e^y-1)^{N-1} \\
&=[y^M]\frac{M!}{(N-1)!} \left( (e^y-1)^N + (e^y-1)^{N-1} \right) \\
&=N\cdot S(M,N) + S(M,N-1) \\
&=S(M+1,N)
\end{split}
where $S(\cdot,\cdot)$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Particular values $F(N,N-1)=1$ and $F(M,N)=0$ for $M<N-1$ easily follow from their definition.